# How to connect to a MySQL database from an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sql, mysql, cocoa-touch

I am trying to connect to a remote mysql database from an iPhone. I have searched many web sites but I did not find any help.  If anyone has worked with this please send a solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you have some experience with server-side programming (like PHP or Rails), you could just create an NSArray from the content of a URL where you establish a connection to the MySQL server and print the results you want in ASCII or XML format.

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/results.php"];
NSArray *sqlResults = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
```

Also useful to help you format the results printed by the server page:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

[A quick google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=objective+c+mysql) will show you the way...

Comment: -1 Wouldn't it be clearer to have linked to mysql-cocoa.sourceforge.net and even state that it indeed does work on iphone.

Comment: Not really. Some people need to learn to use Google before opening a StackOverflow thread. Click the link and you'll see how lazy this question is.