# database connection in iphone

Tags: iphone, mysql

How to connect to remote mysql from my iphone application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468618/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-from-an-iphone

Comment: Specifically look for http://mysql-cocoa.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to develop a web service that can receive your queries. If you are not familiar with some server side language such as PHP, Python, or Ruby, you will have a tougher time. I would recommend that you use a REST framework on the server side that abstracts the database queries for you. Ruby on Rails is a good candidate for this. I'm sure others can recommend other frameworks.

Once you have developed your server side code, you can then access resources from the server with simple REST URLs and NSURLConnection or the ASIHTTPRequest library.

I would read up on each of these things:

- [REST](http://www.xfront.com/REST-Web-Services.html)
- [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/)
- [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

Comment: ya i used php to connect to db..thnks